# Magento 2 - Skip installing a module during setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, module, setup-upgrade

Is there a way that not to install a module during `setup:upgrade`? We have several modules that are not in use but want to keep it in the source such that we can enable it again on-demand.

Comment: What about not enabling the module ? Or disable it before running setup:upgrade ?

Comment: either one is ok

Comment: Do you need them in production environment? Otherwise you can move the requirements to require-dev section instead of require section in your composer.json. Then use ```composer install --no-dev``` to install excluding the require-dev section.

Comment: I need them in production environment. In our case, we want to keep it disable but we will enable it when we need it.